# Wix: create shortcuts for all users (not in public Desktop)

Tags: wix

I want to create Shortcuts for all users, the problem is that the shortcut which created is stored at public desktop. Of course it is visible from everyone. But when I delete it from any user it is deleted for everyone. Is there any way to create Shortcuts in each user's "private" Desktop?
thanks in advance.
PS: i'am quite knew at wix

```
<Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
<Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='MYGUID'>
              <File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' DiskId='1' Source='FoobarAppl10.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
                <Shortcut Id="startmenuFoobar10" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="$(var.AppName)" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="Foobar10.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                <Shortcut Id="desktopFoobar10" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="$(var.AppName)" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="Foobar10.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
              </File>
</Component>
```

Comment: You mean each _current_ user, right? (I don't think there is an easy answer either way.)

Comment: yes  for each current user...   your answer makes me even more desperate :S